# Entity Framework - Will SaveChanges behave correctly if called again after an exception?

Tags: entity-framework

If you call `SaveChanges` and it throws an exception (say, because of a concurrency exception), and then you call it a 2nd time, will `SaveChanges` try to "replay" the same database commands, or will it just "pick up where it left off" or will it just be all messed up and you shouldn't call it again?

And what if it was in an explicit transaction when it threw, and you exited that transaction and then entered an new one and called `SaveChanges` again?

I'm not talking about EF Core, but you can give me the answer for that as well.

Comment: `SaveChanges` will always look at its tracked objects, and whether or not they've been added, modified, or marked for deletion. So if your first attempt fails - if you call `SaveChanges` again right away - you'll just get the same error, since the list of tracked entities is still the same. You'd have to explicitly clear out any "pending" operations, before calling `SaveChanges` again - or just drop the currently used `DbContext` and start over and avoid any of the operations that caused the exception in the first place

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: @Gert - Because even if it works correctly the 2nd time. That doesn't mean that it will always work correctly. Maybe the repeat works only in certain situations (certain Exceptions, certain changes to the DbContext, etc.).